# jquery ajax submit always comes back as successful after validation

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-validate

I've created a form using jquery validate. The form validates correctly and as soon as every field has been validated as correct, it's meant to submit via ajax. This is where the problem appears. I've purposely set incorrect login details for the database so I'm expecting the ajax submit to return with an error, but it always comes back as successful (the debug() confirms that there is a problem connecting to the DB). I've used the correct credentials as well and it submits to the DB and also replys with the same "successful" alert message.

Here's the relative code:

```
$("#form1").validate({
        ignore: "hidden:not(select)",
        rules: {
            //custom rules
        },
        messages:{
            //custom messages
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            //custom error placement
        },
        submitHandler: function(form){
                $.ajax({
                url: "submitForm.php",
                type: "post",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function(){
                    alert("successful");
                },
                error: function(jq,status,message){
                    alert("failed");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure your ajax script does what it is supposed to do?

Comment: @Dieter, yes it's doing exactly as it's supposed to do. I misunderstood how ajax determines what is successful and what is not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are still getting "Successful" is because PHP sends a `200` response in order for the browser to display the PHP error and the `success:` handler checks for a `200` response.

If PHP did not send a `200` response then you would never see PHP errors.

The ideal solution is to do server-side validation as to whether or not the query succeeded and then send back a custom success and error response to AJAX's success handler.

Below is a quick n' dirty demo

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "submitForm.php",
    type: "post",
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json'
    success: function(data){
        alert(data['success']+' : '+data['message']);

        if(data['success']){
            // do successful things
        }
        else{
            // do failure things
        }
    },
    error: function(jq,status,message){
        alert("failed");
    }
});
```

**submitForm.php**

```
<?php
if($query == 'successful'){
    $return['success'] = true;
    $return['message'] = 'Success!';
}
else{
    $return['success'] = false;
    $return['message'] = 'Failed!';
}

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: This was the one that helped me most. I didn't realise that Ajax will reply as successful due to just making a successful call. That was my mistake. I am now sending a response from the server to the ajax call. Also Marcel's answer was very helpful as it explains the concept of how ajax works. Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Glad I could help you understand the relationship between AJAX and the server. And yes, Marcel did make a great post as well especially the `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` concept/logic handling.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to do it.

```
if($("#form1").validate())
{




$.ajax({
                url: "submitForm.php",
                type: "post",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function(){
                    alert("successful");
                },
                error: function(jq,status,message){
                    alert("failed");
                }
            });
            return false;

 }
```

Comment: **This is not correct! `.validate()` will always return true.** The `.validate()` method is only the _initialization_ method of the plugin... you cannot call it like this.  I think you meant [.valid()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)... however, `.valid()` would provide something functionally identical to what the OP is already doing.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
success: function(){
    alert("successful");
},
```

Gets executed when your AJAX call is successful, not when a login is successful. You need to pass a login result response to your JavaScript, such as:

```
success: function(response){
    if ( response === 'successful' )
    {
        alert('success');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('failed to login');
    }
},
```

Also be careful to give a proper response. For example, the response will be a whole HTML page (which we don't really want to pass around), so in your PHP you could do something like this:

```
if ( login_checking_function() )
{
    if ( empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
         strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest')
       )
    {
        echo 'successful';
    }
        else
        {
            // do something for non AJAX call, but successful login
        }
}
```

You check for `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` because jQuery adds this header to the AJAX call, that way you know the page is being requsted via AJAX.