# How I can catch PHP response error with Axios

Tags: javascript, php, axios

I want to catch PHP response errors with Axios.

I have a simple PHP code like this to try to send error to my js file:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$test = array (
    'error' => 'test error!'
);  
echo json_encode($test);
die();
```

And my js with axios like this:

```
axios({
      method: 'post',
      responseType: 'json',
      url: 'test.php'
      data: '1234'
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if ( response.data.error ) {
        console.log(response.data.error) // I show error here            
      }
      else {            
        console.log(response.data);            
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {          
      console.log (error); // it's possible to show error here?
    }
)
```

I can't show error inside `catch` I think because I made `echo json_encode` and Axios can not differenciate between error and normal response.

Is there some way to catch errors inside `catch`?

Comment: A good thing to do is set the http code such as `400` (Bad Request) in the PHP and check the http code in axios, then grab the error message.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/18897704/2191572 because I am 99.99999% positive this has to do with response codes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the error in your catch block, your PHP script must return a HTTP status code other than [2xx Success](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success) with error response.

So in your PHP script you should add a HTTP status code. Example: [How to send HTTP response code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258634/php-how-to-send-http-response-code)

Because axios only treat a response as an error and pass it to the catch block, when it gets a HTTP status code that not in [2xx Success List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success)

[Example from axios:](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)

```
axios.get('/user/12345')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
});
```